# Why wont my Conditional Logic display/run?

Tags: if-statement

```
if (defenseRuns === 1){
defenseRuns = "4-3 Stack with a cover 3 zone.";
}
if (defenseRuns === 2){
defenseRuns = "Dime coverage with a weak side OLB blitz.";
}
if (defenseRuns === 3){
defenseRuns = "Man coverage with weak side stacked backer blitz";
}
if (defenseRuns === 4){
defenseRuns = "Prevent zone coverage with a 4 man rush."; 

defenseRuns = "4-3 Stack with a cover 3 zone.";


if (firstPlay === defenseRuns) {
valueLog ("The defense has fallen apart! the " + playerTeam + " get a 15 yard gain! ");
}

if (firstPlay === "run" && defenseRuns === "Prevent zone coverage with a 4 man rush.") { 
valueLog("Thats a gain of 15 yards. You are now on the 50 yard line with 1:55 on the clock.")
}

if (firstPlay === "pass" && defenseRuns === "Man coverage with weak side stacked backer blitz") { 
valueLog("The Pass is incomplete. Its 2nd and 10 with 1:55 on the clock") 
} 

if (firstPlay === "rpo"  && defenseRuns === "Dime coverage with a weak side OLB blitz."){
valueLog("The play was a hit! 30 yard gain. You are now on the other teams 35 yard line with 1:35 on 
the clock.")
}

if (firstPlay === "play action" && defenseRuns === "4-3 Stack with a cover 3 zone"){
valueLog("You have counterd the defense! 10 Yard gain. You are now on the 45 yard line with 1:43 on 
the clock.")
}
```

Is this conditional logic formatted correctly? My counter displays a number 1-4 and depending on the number, a specific message will appear but it simply does not. Is there any way to fix this? I am also working in jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi @Jason,  looks like you are missing a `}` after the `if (defenseRuns === 4){` .. and maybe an else before the next line `defenseRuns = "4-3 Stack with a cover 3 zone.";`

Comment: It also looks like the code is quite fragile - if you change the text of any of the early setting of defenseRuns then the later if statements won't ever match.  Also you mention showing the message - valueLog is meant to do that - what have you done to debug whehter it is working properly??